# Constructor for mocked object is still getting called?

Tags: python, pytest, python-mock

I am really new to Python and unit tests and I'm trying to write unit tests for a handler right now.

A simplified version of the handler looks something like this:

*some_handler.py*

```py
def handleEvent(event): 
   user = event....
   action = event...
   response = getIsAuthorized(user, action)
   return convertToHttpResponse(response)

getIsAuthorized(user, action):
   ...
   authorizer = SomeAuthorizer()
   return authorizer.isAuthorized(user, action)
```

SomeAuthorizer is a simple class:

*some_authorizer.py*

```py
class SomeAuthorizer(object):
   __init__(self):
      # some instantiation of stuff needed for the 3P client
      ... 
      # creation of some 3P auth client
      self.client = Some3PClient(...)

   is_authorized(user, action): 
      return self.client.is_authorized(user, action)
```

The code itself is working as expected, but my tests are giving me hell.
I got it to work in some circumstances with:

```py
    @patch.object(SomeAuthorizer, 'is_authorized')
    def test_authorization_request_not_authorized(self, mock_is_authorized):
        mock_is_authorized.return_value = False
          
        response = handle_request(test_event("test_user", "testing"))
        assert response == status_code(200, False)
```

But then when another dev ran the tests on their box, it failed and it seemed like the reason was because they didn't have some environment stuff set up locally that the constructor of the Authorizer needed (the errors they got locally were issues creating an instance of SomeAuthorizer when the tests were running). But my understanding was that the constructor shouldn't even be getting called because it's being mocked? Is this not the case?

Any tips on how to get around this? I've been beating my head against the wall trying to understand how the mocks are working and what combination of patch / mock would work but it's not going far.

Comment: Do you want to mock the whole `SomeAuthorizer` class or just the method `SomeAuthorizer.is_authorized()`?

Comment: Could there be code that runs inside the class definition? Could there be a global instance of the class somewhere? Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) just to show the constructor actually being called when it shouldn't be? Can the other dev verify (with a debugger, print traces or otherwise) that the constructor is called?

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano Ideally the entire class but I couldn't find a way to get it to work and let me mock out the is_authorized method the way I want

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'll try to work out a shareable example of it being called in a test. The dev was able to verify that the constructor was being called when the test was run because the trace that resulted from the test was about how it couldn't create the "Some3PClient" because they didn't have some required env values.

Comment: Can you work around the problem by also explicitly mocking the `Some3PClient` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working solution you might want to use as reference. This would mock the whole `SomeAuthorizer` class thus its `__init__()` would not be executed nor any of its methods like `is_authorized()`.

**File tree**

```
$ tree
.
├── some_authorizer.py
├── some_handler.py
└── test_auth.py
```

**some_authorizer.py**

```
class Some3PClient:
    def is_authorized(self, user, action):
        return True  # Real implementation returns True


class SomeAuthorizer(object):
   def __init__(self):
      print("Real class __init__ called")
      self.client = Some3PClient()

   def is_authorized(self, user, action):
      print("Real class is_authorized called")
      return self.client.is_authorized(user, action)
```

**some_handler.py**

```
from some_authorizer import SomeAuthorizer  # The module we want to mock. To emphasize, the version we need to mock is "some_handler.SomeAuthorizer" and not "some_authorizer.SomeAuthorizer".


def handleEvent(event):
   user = "event...."
   action = "event..."
   response = getIsAuthorized(user, action)
   return convertToHttpResponse(response)


def getIsAuthorized(user, action):
   authorizer = SomeAuthorizer()
   return authorizer.is_authorized(user, action)


def convertToHttpResponse(response):
    return (200, response)
```

**test_auth.py**

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from some_handler import handleEvent


def test_real_class():
    response = handleEvent("test_event")
    assert response == (200, True)
    print(response)


@patch("some_handler.SomeAuthorizer")  # As commented in some_handler.py, patch the full path "some_handler.SomeAuthorizer" and not "SomeAuthorizer" nor "some_authorizer.SomeAuthorizer". If you want to patch the latter for all that uses it, you have to reload the modules that imports it.
def test_mock_class(mock_some_authorizer):
    mock_some_authorizer.return_value.is_authorized.return_value = False  # Mock implementation returns False

    response = handleEvent("test_event")
    assert response == (200, False)
    print(response)
```

**Output**

```
$ pytest -q -rP
============================================================================================ PASSES ============================================================================================
_______________________________________________________________________________________ test_real_class ________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Real class __init__ called
Real class is_authorized called
(200, True)
_______________________________________________________________________________________ test_mock_class ________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(200, False)
2 passed in 0.05s
```

Comment: Aghhh yes, thank you so much. The issue was that I was using @patch("authorization.SomeAuthorizer") instead of @patch("some_handler.SomeAuthorizer") when I tried to mock out the entire class instead of just the single method. Tbh I still don't get why that is how it needs to be, but I am grateful and will look into it!

Comment: Because the other files already imported the old version of the `SomeAuthorizer` before the patch has taken effect. If you want the updated patch to reflect on those files that already imported the old version, you have to reload those files via `importlib.reload(sys.modules['some_handler'])` so that they can see the new version. Or better yet as I did in my answer, just patch the version of `SomeAuthorizer` in those importing files :)